# Macros->Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macros

I am new to objective C.

```
  #define DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(ClassID)

  enum {ID = ClassID}; 

   @interface data_derived : data {

   @public
    DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(RM_REQUEST_SESSION) //RM_REQUEST_SESSION = 0x11 declared as enum(which is a const)

  }

  @end
```

> Error:'ClassID undeclared here'

why is this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
An enumeration consists of a set of named integer constants
```

ClassID is not a constant right?

We can give

```
enum {ID = 0};
```

we can also give

```
enum{ID} // now ID automatically assigned as 0
```

we can't give

```
enum {ID = ClassID};
```

because ClassID is not a constant..See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whbyts4t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [this](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/enums.html) link

**EDIT:After seeing the comment**

Instead of setting ClassID in the macro function, return the intented value from the macro and assign that value to ClassID macro in the file itself..
See How I have done an example here..It is a C code..but preprocessor logic for objective C is similiar..

```
#define max(A,B)    ( (A) > (B) ? (A):(B)) 
#define MYVAL  max(2,3)

enum{
    FIRSTVALUE = MYVAL,
    OTHERTHING
};

void main(){
 printf("%d and %d",SOMETHING,OTHERTHING);
return;
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra:I have edited my code.Please see what needs to be changed.ClassID is declared as constant only.

Comment: What is your requirement..what this DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG does

Comment: ID=ClassID(ClassID will take any IDValue eg.RM_REQUEST_SESSION = 0x11 or RM_RESPONSE = 0x12 od RM_RES = 0x13 this value is passed through DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(ClassID) macro).My requirement is to get the any value of message Id passed at runtime.

Comment: where you declaring classID? Also can you post the DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG macro (or atleast a part of it)

Comment: You want ClassID to get the return value of DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG right? Try #define classID DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG()..I am not sure..also I dont know whether DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG function wants a classID argument

Comment: @Krishnabhadra:Yes I want ClassID to get the return value of DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG()..If i define #define CLASSID then i need to declare like this for more than 10 id's.I have enum containing all message id's.I will pass this enum to the macro so that the ID is set with that particular msgId.If i want another msgId to get assigned with the ID then i will sent that particular msgId to the macro.I will use ID in other classes.

Comment: Then your passing classID to the macro DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG so that it will get set there..But I think the problem is that The scope of classID is only in that function (macro) only..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra:yeah.But added line splits in the same above declaration(what i have posted).If line splice is used then the enum will also be initialised along with the macro substitution.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra:its line splices not line splits.If line splice tells the current line and the next line to be merged together

Answer (score 0):

Well, because ClassID is probably not declared there. Macro definition extends only until end of line (unless the end of line is escaped with `\`), so your second line is *not* part of the macro declaration and thus the formal arguments of the macro are not defined there. In other words you have just declared a macro `DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG` that expands to nothing and than tried to declare a symbolic constant (global) ID using undefined value ClassID.

Comment: @interface data_derived : data {
 @public
 DECLARE_RS232_NEWMSG(RM_REQUEST_SESSION)
}
I have defined RM_REQUEST_SESSION = 0x11 as enum in another file;I'm passing only the ClassID and not the ClassName here.With this i'm passing the ClassId but still i get the same error.